# IOS: Managing cached items

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching

I'm thinking to write a class, which will managed all the cashed files my app's creating, like storing persistently the passes to them, then say if app was killed, deleting them on next app launch.

But this doesn't sound that good, I'm thinking if there is a way to tell iOS to delete a file with URL, once the app is killed?

Comment: Oh yeah, really forgot about tmp directory. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understood temp directories is the best scenario for you.

You may want to read this very old but still actual artical from Cocoa With Love by Matt Gallagher. http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/temporary-files-and-folders-in-cocoa.html He shows how to use `mkstemp()` for files and `mkdtemp()` for directories, complete with NSString conversions.